# Image slider link to internal or external page on Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

(Sitefinity 6.x)
I am trying to create an image slider where each image in the page links to an internal or external page. I created a separate library for all the images that I want to show on the slider then using custom MVC widget I display the images in a slider.The problem that I have is there is no place in the image where I can link the image to open an existing internal page or external website.

Is there a way to add a properties to the original Image properties? so that users can select a page (using some sort of page selector just like in the navigation widget) or type in external page to link. If that is not possible, could you give me some ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been creating image rotators using Module Builder in Sitefinity. What you could do is go to Administration -> Module Builder -> Create a Module, call it Image Slider, call the content type Slide. Add a couple fields, for the first call it Image and select Media for the type, this will use an image selector for the interface, then add another field called Link and use Short text for the type, this will hold the url. Unfortunately, Sitefinity doesn't include a Page Selector control as an available field yet so a text field will have to do. Save and activate your module, it will show up under Content -> Types of Content. Go ahead and add a few slides. Sitefinity has created a couple of widgets when you created the module, so if you edit a page, you'll see them under the "Content" widget section, probably at the bottom. Drag it on the page and set it to use the list template. Now open up the Sitefinity Explorer window in their Thunder Visual Studio plugin, under Common Widget Templates, you'll see an Image Slider folder, you'll want to edit the list template since you'll be outputing all the slides into some carousel markup or something. From here you can use the default Sitefinity image control and bind the link to a hyperlink that wraps the image control, this will link each image to whatever is in that field.

Hope that  helps.

Comment: Apparently I could add a new custom field to Images to store the URL, so that's what I did.